# How to select between date range on a materialize v1 date picker

Tags: materialize

I want to use materialize date picker to set select date range from currently to other date. Example: I have 2 input.I click first input select tomorrow date then I click second input it will disable before date. So how do I do? and I always research I saw they use: `$('.datepicker').pickadate();` why using pickadate? and in Materialize document they use datepicker.

Comment: Disable before date?

Comment: Disable mean can not select

Comment: So you want the date-picker to select dynamically a range of dates in which a person can select date from today till like 10 years (for example) but can't select date before today's date, right?